# Create Cloud Endpoint credential with Android Google Sigin

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

The following article from Google shows how to create a credential object for interacting with a Google Cloud Endpoints service, using the older account chooser.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android

However, if you are using Google Sign-In, linked below, how do you create the necessary credential object to build the Google Cloud Endpoints Service?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android

Comment: Please read this link http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html to see if it can help or not

Comment: [This sample code](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java#L322) shows how to construct a GoogleCredential from an OAuth2.0 token, which you can get from Google Sign-In. Do you think that might work for you?

Comment: @Nick Looks like what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Post a self-answer showing a basic snippet if you manage to get it working!

Comment: If it seems there's no integration between Sign-In and Endpoints auth, you could make a feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). If you provide some code showing what you currently have, and point out any documentaiton related to what you'd like, or what is almost working but doesn't quite, it would be processed quite quickly. You could also find out that it is possible, but it would take some investigation and a means to track that this issue had arisen. Usually Stack Overflow is better for user-errors. Best of luck!